# Why doesn't the first SQL work with the "AND" statement like the second statement?

Tags: sql

***Statement 1***

```
USING(country_code)
AND p1.year = p2.year - 5;
```

***Statement 2***

```
ON p1.country_code = p2.country_code
AND p1.year = p2.year - 5;
```

Comment: Because `USING` works with specific columns, the `ON` works with a `conditional expression`. See the [join_condition](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/join-syntax/) info. I'm assuming MySQL/MariaDB is used, as there is no database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `USING` is a *replacement* for `ON`, specifically designed for when the `JOIN` conditions are using keys with the same name.  It doesn't take "extra" conditions -- after all, `ON` provides that functionality and `USING` is basically a short-hand.

If the `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`, you can use a `WHERE` clause:

```
    USING (country_code)
WHERE p1.year = p2.year - 5;
```